# How can I specify the jvm agent id when querying the metrics on the New Relic v1 REST API?

Tags: monitoring, newrelic

I am trying to get JVM metrics from my application, which runs three instances, with three separate JVMs.  I can see the different data that I am interested in in the New Relic dashboard, on the Monitoring -> JVMs tab.  I can also get the information I want for one of those JVMs, by hitting the REST API like so:

```
% curl -gH "x-api-key:KEY" 'https://api.newrelic.com/api/v1/applications/APPID/data.xml?metrics%5B%5D=GC%2FPS%20Scavenge&field=time_percentage&begin=T1&end=T2'
```

(I've replaced the values of some fields, but this is the full form of my request.)

I get a response including a long list of elements like this:

```
  <metric name="GC/PS Scavenge" begin="T1" end="T2" app="MYAPP" agent_id="AGENTID">
    <field name="time_percentage">0.018822634485032824</field>
  </metric>
```

All of the `metric` elements include the same `agent_id` fields, and I never specified which agent to use.  How can I either:

- get metrics for all agents
- specify which agent I am interested in (so I can send multiple requests, one for each JVM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`agent_id` can be a particular JVM instance, and while you can't request for multiple agents at once you can request metrics for a single JVM.

You can get the JVM's agent_id in one of two ways:

1) an API call to

```
https://api.newrelic.com/api/v1/accounts/:account_id/applications/:app_id/instances.xml
```

2) browse to the JVM in the New Relic user interface (use the 'JVM' drop-down at the top right after you select your app), then grab the ID from the URL.

The ID will look something like `[account_id]_i2043442`

Some data is not available broken down by JVM, most notably a call to `threshold_values.xml` won't work if the agent_id isn't an application.

full documentation of the V1 API: http://newrelic.github.io/newrelic_api/